# VScode内のウインドウのサイズがとても小さくなってしまった

Tags: macos, vscode

タイトルの通りです。環境はmac OSです。あるときに、何かのコマンドを押してしまい、それからというものVScode内のウインドウのサイズがとても小さくなってしまって、もちろん実行ボタンの緑三角、プログラム停止ボタンの赤四角も小さくなってしまい不便です。

Ctr+Zを押しても治りませんでしたので（記憶では）、macだけのコマンドのような気もします。一応、VScodeのフォントを大きくしてみましたが、小さいウインドに大きな文字という、なんだか違和感です。

ここで言う、ウインドが小さいとは、ウインドウおよびその他のボタンのサイズだけが小さくなっているということです。コード画面は文字サイズを大きくして対処しています。

戻したいです。どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

画像に示したショートカット（Ctrl + = など）で、ボタンやツールバー含めたUI全体を拡大縮小することができます。これを押してしまったのかもしれません。逆にUIを拡大するショートカットを押すか、Command Palette（Ctrl + Shift + P）から画像にあるコマンドを打つと、元に戻せると思います。

[image: VSCodeのキーボードショートカット]